# How to handle global variable inside recursive function?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to traverse over directory and its subdirectories to extract files. The code below works fine, however, the global variable "DECOMPRESSED_FILES_COUNTER" is incremented only within the first directory.
Ignore the "IS_EXTRACTED" variable(this is for other use)
Here is a little part of my script:

```
FILE_OUTPUT_HIDE=/dev/null 2>&1
DECOMPRESSED_FILES_COUNTER=0
CURRENT_PATH=$(pwd)

function extractFiles(){
    IS_EXTRACKED=""
    if ( file "$FILE_I"  | grep -w 'zip' >$FILE_OUTPUT_HIDE )
    then
        unzip -o $FILE_I >$FILE_OUTPUT_HIDE
        let "DECOMPRESSED_FILES_COUNTER++"
    elif ( file "$FILE_I"  | grep -w 'gzip' >$FILE_OUTPUT_HIDE )
    then
         gunzip -k -f -N $FILE_I >$FILE_OUTPUT_HIDE
         let "DECOMPRESSED_FILES_COUNTER++"
    elif ( file "$FILE_I"  | grep -w 'bzip2' >$FILE_OUTPUT_HIDE )
    then
        bzip2 -k -d -f  $FILE_I >$FILE_OUTPUT_HIDE
        let "DECOMPRESSED_FILES_COUNTER++"
    else
        IS_EXTRACKED=false
    fi
}

function recursiveMode(){
    for FILE_I in *; do
        if [ -d "$FILE_I" ]; then
            (cd -- "$FILE_I" && recursiveMode)
        fi
        extractFiles 
    done
}
```

Example:

omri@omri-pc:/mnt/c/users/omri/mission$ ./myScript -r newFolder

Assuming that "newFolder" had 3 archives files and in its subfolder "otherFolder" had 2 archives files.

I expect the DECOMPRESSED_FILES_COUNTER to be 5, but the actual value is 3 even though all files were extracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subshell you use to localize the change in the directory causes changes to the variable to only persist in that subshell. Use `pushd` and `popd` instead to change and restore the working directory.

```
function recursiveMode(){
    for FILE_I in *; do
        if [ -d "$FILE_I" ]; then
            pushd "$FILE_I"
            recursiveMode
            popd
        fi
        extractFiles 
    done
}
```

However, given the number of `bash`-only features you are using, you may as well use another one: the `**` glob pattern to do the recursion for you.

```
shopt -s globstar

counter=0
extractFile () {

    if file "$1" | grep -qw bzip2; then
       bzip2 -k -d -f "$1"
    elif file "$1" | grep -qw gzip; then
       gunzip -k -f -N "$1"
    elif file "$1" | grep -qw zip; then
       unzip -o "$1"
    else
       return        
    fi > /dev/null
    ((counter++))
}

for f in **/*; do
    extractFile "$f"
done
```

Comment: hello, 
it's working but when I tried to encapsulate the for into a function and call from another function somewhere it won't recursively.
for example, it will extract and count files only in the current folder.
thanks

Comment: sorry,
forgot to add shopt -s globstar to the script..
its working perfect.
thanks